# Flying over the map with mouse drag?

Tags: three.js

How to realize flying over the map, like http://rainforest.arkivert.no/#kart.
Should I change camera coordinates or change model position?
What is the best solution? Maybe there are ready examples?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you change camera coordinates rather than transforming the whole scene. You should be able to easily find examples on how to modify the camera.

Take a look at the implementation of [OrbitControls.js](http://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js) in that [sample](http://view-source:http://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_orbit).